# preg_replace on require line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to just keep the file name and remove all other characters.

```
require_once($GLOBALS['root'] . '/library/test/TestFactory.php');
```

Want it to look like this:

```
/library/test/TestFactory.php
```

So far have this

```
$string = "require_once($GLOBALS['root'] . '/library/test/TestFactory.php');"
$string = preg_replace("~^.*?(?=\/)~i", "", $string);
```

I get this but just missing the end characters of "');" Any help would be appreciated.

```
/library/test/TestFactory.php');
```

UPDATE, on another instance i get something like this but my regex won't read it well as it don't have a / in there.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $this->config . 'display.php
```

I would think i would want just display.php

Comment: assuming that all of your requires are in the form of `a . /b`, you'd be better off just using a strpos on the `. '/` bit and using string operations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done unless you have a regex that parses the language. Any kludge attempt is futile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following for both of your cases.

```
$str = preg_replace('~^[^.]*\.[^\'"]*[\'"]([^\'"]+).*~m', '$1', $str);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/220575)

Comment: it fails with a few things for example:
require_once($GLOBALS['root'].'/translate/LanguagesController.php');
running php 5.4.24

Comment: ok i see what problem is, what i have is using double quotes:
require_once($GLOBALS['root']."/public/themes/ThemeUpload.php");
if you can also adapt that too would be great

Comment: just saw another two that isn't working
require_once('OAuth.php');
require_once '../../csrest_general.php';
it comes out as ");" should be just OAuth.php
and other one comes as ";" should be ../../csrest_regeneral.php

Comment: seems like there isn't ever gonna be an exact regex for all, added last change but it broke these ones for example.
require_once($GLOBALS['root'] . '/translate/public/' . $language . '.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/' . $className . '.php');

Comment: what would be a good solution? i was thinking of doing an if statement with preg_match and being able to use different preg_replace depending on what type of line it was found.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a regular expression, you will need to use a matching group to do the replacement.

```
$string = preg_replace("~[^/]*([^']*).*~i", '$1', $string);
```

- `[^/]*` - all characters that are not a `/`
- `([^']*)` - matching group on all characters that are not a `'`
- `.*` - the rest of the string

Test it on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aF4iN7/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can also grab the match instead of replace.

```
(\/.*\/[^']+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/8

```
$re = "~(/.*/[^']+)~i";
$str = "require_once(\$GLOBALS['root'] . '/library/test/TestFactory.php');";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I think the regular expression would be a lot more readable as `$re = "~(/.*/[^']+)~i";`. If you use `~` instead of `/` you can avoid a lot of escaping. The OP is also trying to do a replace, not a match.

Answer (score 1):

The below works assuming the file path consists of alphanumeric characters, forward slashes or periods.  If not, you can just adjust it and add in any additional characters to this piece `(\/[\w\/\.]+)`:

```
$string = "require_once(\$GLOBALS['root'] . '/library/test/TestFactory.php');";
$string = preg_replace("~^[^/]+(/[\w/\.]+).*~i", "$1", $string);
echo $string;
```

Note that I had to escape the dollar sign in your test string.